# How to forecast in ARIMA within limits, in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I'm forecasting a percentage in R, so my condifence intervals should stay within 0-100%,

I read on "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" it should be done with a log. Like this:

```
# Bounds
a <- 50
b <- 400
# Transform data and fit model
fit <- log((eggs-a)/(b-eggs)) %>%
  ets(model="AAN", damped=FALSE)
fc <- forecast(fit, h=50)
```

For my case, I'm trying to forecast room$rate, so I tried to replace eggs with rate but it didn't work. Any idea's?

Comment: Please explain what "didn't work", preferably with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: When I tried to make the log, I got this error: 
    Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example